# traceroute mac in mininet

Tags: sdn, mininet, traceroute

In mininet I want to find out through which switches ping goes. For example from PC1 (h1) to PC3 (h3). I already tried:

```
h1 traceroute mac ip h3
```

or

```
11:00:00:00:00:00 traceroute mac 33:00:00:00:00:00
```

But it didnt work. "Normal" traceroute (`h1 traceroute h2`) is working (only destination address is in output). But I need to find out the path of ping.

[image: topology]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traceroute only works with L3, so its not possible to find route. 
So i use flow-tables in switches, where is shown through which port the path goes.

For example, if I want to know the path of mac address: 66:00:00:00:00 a look at the output port. And thanks to ryu gui topology is easy to find way.

Answer (score 0):

try to traceroute via the host using xterm, not from mininet cli. try with more than two hosts.